# undefined references to `__stack_chk_fail' during pintos installation

Tags: kernel, pintos

I am trying to install pintos in Ubuntu 13.10 but while doing the 'make' command in the thread folder, I got the error

"more undefined references to `__stack_chk_fail' follow
make[1]: *** [kernel.o] Error 1 "

As iam encountering this error for the first time, I can't figure out this.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu's GCC by default enables the `-fstack-protector` flag, which defends against stack overflow attacks ([more info on their wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags)). You'll have to add `-fno-stack-protector` to the compiler flags.